# How to use arrows and enter to select option from autocomplete options?

Tags: autocomplete

On an older installation I had it somehow configured, so that I if I had an autocomplete list that I could bring up with tab, the first item was highlighted and I could use my arrows to navigate the list and confirm with enter. I don't remember how I set this up, any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using fish instead of bash in this older installation:

```
#apt-get install fish  
#fish
```

(yes fish is installable from debian repository in jessie, i dont know if it is on debian 9)

Then you can change your default shell in /etc/passwd from bash to fish.

When installed, it has a very cool manual on debian in file:///usr/share/doc/fish/index.html

You will be able to configure it via a very cool web interface, by using this command:

```
 fish_config
```

Comment: I just shut down my pc, will give it a try soon.

Comment: Fish looks really nice, pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: It is a very nice shell! but no very nice for shell scripting, for that i prefer bash instead! But i think that is not a problem, if you consider the advantages of this shell !

Answer (score 1):

That might have been the `zsh` shell. In `zsh`, that's the behaviour you obtain if you run (or typically, add to your `~/.zshrc`):

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
```

(where that selection style is enabled as soon as there are at least 2 entries to choose from).

There are a lot more completion tuning you can do with `zstyle` commands. Or you can use the `compinstall` function for a menu-based interface that does the hard work for you.

```
autoload compinstall && compinstall
```

Comment: I assume this would work too, but I am already happy with the fish shell.